# GetTempFileName not working in silverlight out-of-browser

Tags: silverlight, permissions

I have a Silverlight application that runs out-of-browser. I was previously able to get the statement Path.GetTempFileName to work when I run out-of-browser but not when running locally. Now this is failing out-of-browser also.
I am getting this error
Message
File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied.

I am editing this because I have new information. I have another application which is very similar where I am not getting the problem. That is Path.GetTempFileName works fine. I cannot see any differences between the applications.

I need some hints as to what could be different between the two application. I am running both locally in debug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Out of Browser settings in the Silverlight Project Properties page?  There is a checkbox "Require elevated trust when running out of browser.

On the ShortCut not working.  Try uninstalling the app from the Control panel and reinstalling.  Then try it again.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The idea of uninstalling and reinstalling didn't help. I do have Enable out-of-browser checked but I do not have Require elevated trust checked for either in-browser or out of browser. Is this correct?

Comment: Checking the check box require elevated trust when running out-of-browser seem to work.

Comment: Checking the check box Require elevated trust when running out of browser causes Visual Studio to crash. It is not set for the application that is working. So I am still searching for an answer.

Comment: I have used that check box many times without a problem.  Maybe there are updates to VS or the Silverlight SDK that you need to update.

Comment: It seem to be a protection problem, when I check out the InBrowserSettings.xml file I was able to check the check the box. However this didn't solve my problem of Path.GetTempFile. I'm not sure why it seem to work before.